# Add new packing method one rate in fedex in magento1

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to add new packing method one rate in fedex packing serive in magento1. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

I had a reply from fedex saying
As per the Developer Resource Guide- To specify FedEx One Rate Pricing Option in the Web Service Transaction, perform the following steps:

1. Specify the "FEDEX_ONE_RATE" ShipmentSpecialService.
2. The FedEx Packaging Types that are valid/available with the One Rate pricing option are the following:

   - FEDEX_ENVELOPE
   - FEDEX_SMALL_BOX
   - FEDEX_MEDIUM_BOX
   - FEDEX_LARGE_BOX
   - FEDEX_EXTRA_LARGE_BOX
   - FEDEX_PAK
   - FEDEX_TUBE
3. Specify a U.S. origin and a U.S. destination.

Note: Intra-Hawaii shipments are not allowed for One Rate pricing.

4. Specify one of the following FedEx Express services:

   - FIRST_OVERNIGHT
   - PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT
   - STANDARD_OVERNIGHT
   - 2_DAY
   - 2_DAY_AM
   - EXPRESS_SAVER

Note: Web Services clients can request both One Rate and weight-based (non-One Rate) rates in a single RateRequest by specifying "FEDEX_ONE_RATE" as a ServiceOptionType in the RateRequest.variableOptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood you need to add custom container type for that you need to rewrite **Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Fedex** in your module.

I am mentioning changes that you need to done after rewrite:

```
 protected $_customizableContainerTypes = array('YOUR_PACKAGING',
                                                'one_rate');
```

Need to update following portion in getcode() method:

```
'packaging' => array(
    'FEDEX_ENVELOPE' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('FedEx Envelope'),
    'FEDEX_PAK'      => Mage::helper('usa')->__('FedEx Pak'),
    'FEDEX_BOX'      => Mage::helper('usa')->__('FedEx Box'),
    'FEDEX_TUBE'     => Mage::helper('usa')->__('FedEx Tube'),
    'FEDEX_10KG_BOX' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('FedEx 10kg Box'),
    'FEDEX_25KG_BOX' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('FedEx 25kg Box'),
    'YOUR_PACKAGING' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Your Packaging'),
    'one_rate' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('one Rate')
),          

'containers' => array('YOUR_PACKAGING','one_rate'),
```

After that you need to change getContainerTypes method:

```
return array('YOUR_PACKAGING' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('Your Packaging'),
                'one_rate' => Mage::helper('usa')->__('one Rate'));
```

I hope this will help you.
Please let me know if you have queries.

Comment: ok thanks hardik i will check this functionality & whether or not fedex approves it.

Comment: It should work fine as we have already implemented this.

Comment: Thanks hardik just 1 last advice i need to implement  "the One Rate special service to be included in the rate or label request. " <q0:SpecialServicesRequested>

      <q0:SpecialServiceTypes>FEDEX_ONE_RATE</q0:SpecialServiceTypes>

    </q0:SpecialServicesRequested> Will the above solution be same.

Comment: As I checked it seems to be like above.
Please accept the answer if its helpful

Comment: I used your code but it doesn't work as i expected. I have updated my question would like to know if i m going in right direction. If there is any module that you can suggest it would be grateful